# Is there a way to reduce time taken for a-b' related operation in matlab where a and b are large column vectors?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to do an operation that goes like: `(exp((a-b').^2)*(diag(c)*d))`, where `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are column vectors. The sizes of `a` and `b` are large so `a-b'` exceeds the maximum limit for matrix size in MATLAB. I then converted this to a loop that goes over each value of `a`:

```matlab
d=zeros(length(a),1);
for i=1:length(a)
    d(i)=(exp((a(i)-b').^2)*(c.*d));
end
```

This makes the code take a long time to run because this operation is called a lot. Is there any way to reduce the time taken for this?

Comment: It’s an expensive operation, there might not be many opportunities to speed this up.  Instead of multiplying by `ones(...)`, use `sum`.

Comment: Setting `a=rand(5,1); b=rand(5,1); c=rand(5,1);` it doesn't work.

Comment: since you dot-product with `diag(c)` which only has non-zero elements on the diagonal, most of your computation of exp(a-b') is wasted. you only need to compute the diagonal of that matrix, which is `exp( (a-b).^2 )`, then multiply with `c`. in other words, the non-zero diagonal in your first 2 terms, i.e. `(exp((a-b').^2).*diag(c))`, can be computed using `exp( (a(:)-b(:)).^2 ).*c(:)`

Comment: I'll try using sum, thank you.

Comment: c is a row vector, sorry for the mistake in the question

Comment: Thank you for pointing out about the non zero elements are a more efficient way to do this, I'll try this now.

Comment: In your first expression, is `d` initialized to zero as well? In the loop version, you are multiplying by `d`,  but also changing `d`, which means there’s a cumulative process going on that doesn’t happen in your original expression.

Comment: Please add a [mre] for your original expression, so that we can test any alternative implementations and see it produces matching results.